# How to upgrade my MacBook Air from 10.6 to 10.9?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, macbook-pro, software-update

I was given a MacBook Air from my step mother because she never used it. I tried upgrading everything but every time I try to update it, it stays the same old version. Do i need to go to the store first?

It's still on OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Hi - and welcome to Ask Different! As for your MacBook Air - you can upgrade to 10.9 using the following instructions from Apple (http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/). And, if you get stuck, don't hesitate to ask more questions here - or visit an Apple Store for help. That is what they do.

Comment: We may need a little more information here in order to help - were you able to download the 10.9 (Mavericks) installer - and what happened when you tried to apply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the Mac App Store (/Applications/App Store.app)
2. Download the OS X Mavericks app.
3. Run it from the /Applications folder if it doesn't automatically run.
4. Follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I was working on 10.6.8. To my knowledge the upgrade is easier than you think. I hope the following steps are accurate and give you the requested outcome, a working OS X Mavericks (10.9).

**1. Click on the little Apple logo in the top left corner of your screen.**

[image]

**2. A drop-down menu should appear looking like this (see below). Press `Software Update...`.**

[image]

**3. Then the following window should pop up (see below). Press `Show Details`.**

[image: List item]

**4. The window below should appear. In line 1 (`Mac OS X Update`) you should see under version `10.9.1`. (Ignore the other options for now). Make sure the blue box in front of `Mac OS X Update` is ticked and all others un-ticked.**

[image]

**5. Finally, there are 3 buttons at the bottom of this window looking like this.      Instead of 5 items (like in the image) it should say `Install 1 Item`. Press this button and from there you should have clear guidance.**

[image]

Good Luck!!

Comment: Major updates (10.x) are not distributed through Software Update.

Comment: My bad, I forgot about that completely :/ Thanks for correcting me. I have up-voted yours so mine does not get in the way. I forgot there was an App Store for that long.

Comment: Felix is correct that you need to install 10.6.8 before the App store will allow you to upgrade further.

Comment: @bmike She mentions though at the end of her post that `It's still on OS X 10.6.8`. Thus, I guess my post is fairly useless.